# How to write a Python type hint that specifies a Callable that takes certain parameters or 0 parameters?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have the following code

```py
def func1(f: Callable):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorator


@func1
def func2(parameter: str):
    # do something else
    ...
```

I want to specify that func1 takes a Callable that has either 1 parameter of a certain type (in this case, a str), or no parameters at all so that I could use it not just with func2, but also with another function that takes no parameters like the following function

```py
@func1
def func3():
    # this function doesn't take any parameters
```

Obviously even if there is a solution, it wouldn't actually be effective because type hints are ignored anyway, but I would like to add actual validation using Pydnatic, that's why I want to specify that the function must have a parameter of a certain type or no parameters at all.

Comment: Can you use `Union[Callable[…], Callable[…]]`?

Comment: There's no "parameters at all" because function signature will have one. What you should rather do is to give default value (i. e. NULL and of you get the NULL then you act as no arg is provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to specify that func1 takes a Callable that has either 1 parameter of a certain type (in this case, a str), or no parameters at all

Use the union of the two signatures:

```
 func : Callable[[str], Any] | Callable[[], Any])
```

Comment: Note that the syntax using `|` is only available in Python 3.10 and better.